# How to increase the increment of n if you want to iterate over every nth value of an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

I'm trying to figure out how to increase the value of `n` so that I can iterate over an array multiple times while only grabbing certain elements at a time.

So let's say,

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
final_array = []
array.map.with_index do |x,i| 
   num = 2
    final_array << x if (i+1) % num == 0
    num += 1
end
```

This will only run as far as `i % 2` and won't run for `3` or `4` or anything. I need to collect all the elements at `i % 2`, then `i % 3`, etc. How do I do that?

Comment: Not clear what you mean.

Comment: dbz got it. Basically I needed to be able to grab every 2 elements, then every 3, then every 4. And I couldn't figure out how to increment that when I wrote the loop

Comment: It would be helpful if you would edit to show your desired result (as, for example, @Stefan has shown in his answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about time complexity i.g. `O(n*m)` vs `O(n)`, you can make a nested loop.

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
divisors = [1, 2, 3]
numbers_by_divisor = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }

divisors.each do |divisor|
  numbers.each do |number|
    numbers_by_divisor[divisor] << number if (number + 1) % divisor == 0
  end
end
```

The `numbers_by_divisor` hash will be a hash of the arrays you want, with the key for each array being the `divisor`.

If you don't care about separating those numbers into different arrays, instead of a `numbers_by_divisor` hash just have an array called `divisible_numbers`:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
divisors = [1, 2, 3]
divisible_numbers = []

divisors.each do |divisor|
  numbers.each do |number|
    divisible_numbers << number if (number + 1) % divisor == 0
  end
end
```

The latter can be done in a more "Ruby" way with a `select` and `any` statement:

```
numbers.select do |number|
  divisors.any? { |divisor| (number + 1) % divisor == 0 }
end
```

Comment: Ah perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!! :DDDD

Comment: @SiouxsieAsylum can you mark this as the correct answer if it was what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

(2..5).map { |n| (0...numbers.size).step(n).map { |i| numbers[i] } }
#=> [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [1, 4, 7, 10], [1, 5, 9], [1, 6]]
```

You can also replace the first `map` with `flat_map` to get a flat array, i.e.:

```
(2..5).flat_map { |n| (0...numbers.size).step(n).map { |i| numbers[i] } }
#=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 4, 7, 10, 1, 5, 9, 1, 6]
```